# Get SD card and executable path in Android and iOS with Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

- How do I get the SD card path and how do I get the executable path in Android and iOS using Delphi XE5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`System.IoUtils.TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath). The SD card path is obtained by using `TPath.GetDocumentsPath`, and the base directory of the app should be found with `TPath.GetHomePath`.

```
uses
  IOUtils;


var
  AppPath, CardPath: string;


  AppPath := TPath.GetHomePath;
  CardPath :- TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
```

There are several other system path related functions in `TPath` as well, including these (and many others - you'll have to see which apply to Android and iOS, as the docs aren't clear)

```
GetTempPath
GetPublicPath
GetCameraPath
GetMusicPath
GetDownloadsPath
```

Comment: Thank You very much.
Just not to the peoples, that Delphi XE5 may not recognise it because of unknown reason, and you need to restart the IDE if it doesnt.