# DELPHI XE5 Android - SAVE / LOAD file from SDCard

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5 for Android developing.

I like to save and load TStringList to text file on SDCard.
When I save TStringList to file all is OK. After saving I can call LoadFromFile and file is loaded.

**The problem is when I close the application and open it again. File does not exist?**
This is file location `FileName := '/data/data/[com.MY.APP]/files/File.txt'`

Under application user permissions = **Write external stoage : True**

**Do I need to save the file to another folder?**

Thx for help.

This in my code and settings.

```
procedure LOAD;
var
  TextFile: TStringList;
  FileName: string;
begin
     TextFile := TStringList.Create;
    try
      FileName := Format('%s/File.txt', [GetHomePath]);
      if FileExists(FileName) then
      begin
        TextFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);
        Memo1.Lines.Text := TextFile.Text
      end
      else
        ShowMessage('File not exists!');
    finally
      TextFile.Free;
    end;     

end;

procedure SAVE;
var
  TextFile: TStringList;
  FileName: string;
begin   
    TextFile := TStringList.Create;
    try
      FileName := Format('%s/File.txt', [GetHomePath]);
      TextFile.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
      TextFile.SaveToFile(FileName);
    finally
      TextFile.Free;
    end;     
end;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use `TPath.Combine()` instead of `Format()`. Are you sure the SDCard path starts with `/data/data/` and not just `/data`? How are you retriving the HomePath?  Also, why use a separate `TStringList` instead of using `Memo.Lines.Load...()` and `Memo.Lines.Save...()`?

Comment: GetHomePath is system function from System.SysUtils

Separate TStringList is just for demo.


If I Use just /data/ I get exception
'Cannot create file "/data/com.debersek.KKP/files/File.txt". Not a directory'.

Comment: You're not saving anywhere near the SD card. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18857868/62576).

Comment: Thx for help. This is working for me:

`AppPath := TPath.GetHomePath;
FileName := TPath.Combine(AppPath, 'File.txt');`

Answer (score 3):

yes,

```
AppPath := TPath.GetHomePath; 
FileName := TPath.Combine(AppPath, 'File.txt');
```

is working fine.
do not forget to add the unit System.IOUtils to your uses clause.

thank you xJernej.